# How to predicate the nested objects ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to predicate the nested objects value here is a structure of nested objects.

```
@interface APContact : NSObject
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSArray <APPhone *> *phones;
@end

@interface APPhone : NSObject
@property (nullable, nonatomic, strong) NSString *number;
@end
```

I am trying to predicate like this as show in below block of code.
I want to predicate the `number` string. how to do this

```
for (APContact *contact in duplucateDataArray) {
    NSMutableArray *countArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSPredicate *morningAttendees  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K.%K MATCHES %@",@"phones[0]",@"number", contact.phones[0].number];
    NSArray <APContact*> *predicateContact = [duplucateDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:morningAttendees];
    NSLog(@"predicate contact%@",predicateContact);
}
```

On running above code getting below exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<APContact 0x2824da6d0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key phones[0].'
```

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object (
    "+91 88815 12534"
).
```

Any suggestions would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove phones[0] as error says you can not use phones[0] APContact has the key phones.

Use below line -

```
 NSPredicate *morningAttendees  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.%K.%K MATCHES %@",@"phones",@"number", contact.phones[0].number];
```

Comment: This give me error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object (
    "+1 (888) 123-1725"
).'`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `MATCHES` with `LIKE`.

`MATCHES` assumes your argument is a regex, `LIKE` assumes your argument is string with wildcard symbols. [source](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html)

Also, when using nested predicates use `ANY`, `SOME` or `ALL` operators.

```
NSPredicate *morningAttendees  = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY phones.number LIKE %@",contact.phones[0].number];
```